# How to divide one row by another with same value in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I have a dataframe following this pattern:

| Measure | Key | mai/21 | jun/21 | jul/21 | ... | mar/22 | apr/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Units | 4040 | 100 | 102 | 104 | ... | 200 | 204 |
| Total Value | 4040 | 10500 | 10700 | 11000 | ... | 22000 | 22200 |
| Units | 3230 | 120 | 130 | 140 | ... | 230 | 240 |
| Total Value | 3230 | 120000 | 130000 | 140000 | ... | 345000 | 360000 |

I need to get a average value per unit and per key, so for every key I have in the dataframe, I need to get the total value row and divide by units row, so I get the average value per unit of each month, and the results needs to follow the same as the input. Just like that:

| Measure | Key | mai/21 | jun/21 | jul/21 | ... | mar/22 | apr/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value per Units | 4040 | 105 | 104.90 | 105.77 | ... | 110 | 108.82 |
| Value per Units | 3230 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | ... | 1500 | 1500 |

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please also include your expected output. Thank you. Also, if the units are always smaller than your total value, you can try `df.groupby('Key').max()/df.groupby('Key').min()`

Comment: Can you give more data sample data with some different keys and also, post your expected ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it, revised after the question was updated

```
i=0
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
while (i < len(df)):
    df2.loc[len(df2)] = ['Value per unit', df.iloc[i,1]] + df.iloc[i+1,2:].divide(df.iloc[i,2:] ).tolist()
    i+=2

df2
```

```
    Measure          Key    mai/21  jun/21               jul/21     mar/22  apr/22
0   Value per unit  4040    105.0   104.901961       105.769231     110.0   108.823529
1   Value per unit  3230    1000.0  1000.000000     1000.000000     1500.0  1500.000000
```

Comment: I was providing more info in the original question when you answered, but I think this should do the job with some adjusts.

Comment: @LucasWerner, updated the solution. is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Measure').groupby('Key').apply(lambda x: (x.T['Total Value'] / x.T['Units']).drop('Key')).reset_index()
df2['Measure'] = 'Value per units'
df2[df.columns]
```

For better understanding what lambda does, data for a single key can be extracted and checked separately:

```
df.set_index('Measure').groupby('Key').get_group(4040)
```

Besides being more readable, this solution is also about 3x faster than the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't make it clear enough and I will update my question with further details. I need the ouput exactly as it was in the input, but adding one row with "Measure" as "Value per Unit" and put the results in this row.

Comment: @LucasWerner You can use reset_index() to move 'Key' back to columns and then you can prepend 'Measure' which will have constant value as I understand.